Why is my kittens hair falling out in circular patches?
I have a 10 week old kitten who has been losing hair in circular patterns.  It's on her back in 2 places, on her left leg, and on the top of her head. No itching.  I've treated her for ear mites. I've used Viodine medicated shampoo.  I cleaned her with Chlorhexidine on those areas.  Nothing is stopping it.

Circular patterns of hair loss is a sign of ringworm; take the kitten to a vet.
